# Trying to understand and translate a small bit of VB code

Tags: vb.net

I'm in the middle of transferring some VB code to another language, but I don't understand what's supposed to be happening here.

```
Dim foo(7,0) as Date
```

Then later in the code I get something like `foo(5,3)` and I believe the output to be a Date object.  There is no function written to describe `foo` so I'm assuming it's a multi-dimensional array.  But cast as a Date?  I'm confused, please help.

Comment: I am guessing a 2 dimensional array of Dates. Each element in the array would be a Date.

Comment: You can declare a 2D array with `Dim foo(,) As Date` or with `Dim foo As Date(,)`. Those two snippets are equivalent. If you want to create an array then you have to specify the size. If you specify the size on the declaration then you can only use the first syntax.

Comment: What other language? If you tell us what then someone who knows both can tell this VB in that and help you understand

Comment: 2D array of size 8x1 with Date as type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's going on their either, because this:

```
Dim foo(7,0) as Date
```

declares a two dimensional array that is effectively a one dimensional array because the second dimension has an upper bound of 0...

... and then you claim that the second dimension is later indexed with 3, which is outside the bounds. `foo(5, 0)` would be fine, but the sixth row (if you want to think of the 5 that way) has 1 column, so retrieving the fourth is an IndexOutOfRangeException. Presumably this has been `ReDim`'d at some point between then and now

To have the debugger help you out, run the code, stop on it and point to `foo` or look in the LOCALS window:

[image]

Bounded in red is the variable analyzer as a tooltip and in the locals. It shows Date to be a 2D array. It also helpfully lists all the contents. Bounded in blue is the error you get if you try and access index 3 of an array that stops at index 0

Make that 2D array actually have an appreciable width:

[image]

And you can see it's just a block of Date

Comment: Thanks to you and @jmcilhinney I now have a better understanding of what's happening and VB's language structures.  Your "ReDim" comment helped me track down a function where `foo` was being passed by reference and modified.